# How to wait for threads' status of another process in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I want to create a monitoring thread to monitor other processes' status in linux kernel, so when they exited, the monitoring thread will know it immediately.

I use `kthread_create`() to run a wait function, this function is blocking to call sys_wait4() to wait another process's child processes, As it's document, I set the first `pid` argument as `-pgid` (pgid is the process id which i want to monitored), but this syscall always return `ECHILD`.

I read the source code of linux kernel, it is because this syscall will set a task struct to current process (which is create to monitor other processes without any child processes).

Is there any other syscall that could implement my purpose？Anyone please give me some help on this? Thank you!

Comment: check this link http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/2/wait

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I have read this documents about wait/waitpid, so i know it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but I wish you will get your answer soon.